# How to perform Server.Transfer(or similar) in WebApi or api-based application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Here's my case:

1. HTML and script loaded
2. JS make ajax call to get data
3. Server found that user do not have permission to view the data and return error message

I would like to perform something similar to asp.net webforms's `Server.Transfer` now to show user the 403 page, and also the status code 403. But i'm not sure how to do it in js.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (considering `xhttp` is your Request object:

```
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    if(xhttp.ResponseText == 'error')
    {
        window.location = "http://www.example.com";
    }
}
```